# Heteroscedasticity: When is it OK?

Tags: regression, residuals, heteroscedasticity, ordered-logit, scatterplot

The point of the last analysis in my paper was to check on the basis of which predictor variables the answers to moral dilemmas can be explained.
Predictor variables are continuous: dark personality triad (Machiavellianism, narcissism and psychopathy), empathy (cognitive and affective) and thinking style (rational and experiential)
The criterion variable is the answers to moral dilemmas that can be utilitarian or deontological. It is also continuous, but has only 6 degrees. The tendency towards lower numbers means utilitarianism, and towards higher ones deontologism.

My original idea was to perform a hierarchical regression in two blocks. However, I got quite pronounced heteroskedasticity. However, I got 6 lines, which somehow justifies such a plot given the characteristics of the dependent variable. The direction of regression and distribution seem normal.

I would ask for help if someone can justify to me what would be best to do. Is it to do White residual correction, ordinal logistic regression or is there a justification to proceed with the hierarchical regardless of heteroskedasticity, given the characteristics of the criterion variable and how then to best justify it?

Comment: Heteroscedasticity can be assumed irrelevant when the only objective is prediction, pure and simple.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. Can you elaborate that a bit more?

Comment: Leo Breiman's paper on the Two Cultures of prediction vs understanding is a good place to start. The classic approach to modeling, even before any data is gathered as would be done wrt many PhD dissertations, assumes a careful process of hypothesis generation leading to insight and understanding based on strict observance of all the assumptions underlying modeling. Prediction, on the other hand, relaxes most of those classic modeling assumptions. Call it data mining but automatic, algorithmic methods break the assumptions and rules with the goal of increasingly accurate predictions.

Comment: Okey, I will definitely check that out. Thank you! So in essence you are actually proposing that I don't do any transformation of residuals or what not but just continue with linear regression?

Comment: What is your goal?

Comment: If you address the ordinal nature of the response variable reasonably well, then you do not have to worry about heteroscedasticity. Like logistic regression, the model allows and automatically takes care of heteroscedasticity.

Comment: My goal is to explain the proportion of variance in responses to moral dilemmas based on each predictor.

Comment: I know that logistic regression is not sensitive to heteroscedasticity. But with it I lose a lot of variability in the answers and that’s why I preferred to continue with linear regression. So I wonder if there is anything else I can do to address heteroscedasticity. I had already tried White's correction and embedding the syntax of Hayes and Cai, but nothing helped.
Should I just give up and do the logistics?

Comment: I know I can do ordinal regression. I’ve done binary before, so I won’t lose so much variability. But honestly, this research is for my thesis and the ordinal we never did in college.
I was told that it is very complicated for someone who does not understand it..